# ANTLR4 - using hidden Tokens in parser rules

Tags: antlr, grammar, antlr4

I'm a complete noob with ANTLR, so apologies if this is a really basic question.

I'm trying to parse a file that has a weird JSON-like syntax. These files are huge, hundreds of MB, so I'm avoiding creating the parse tree and I'm just using grammar actions to manipulate the data into what I want.

As usual, I'm sending Whitespaces and Newlines to the HIDDEN channel. However, there are a couple cases where it'd be helpful if I could detect that the next character is one of those, because that delimits the property value.
Here's an excerpt from a file

```
  game_speed=4
  mapmode=0
  dyn_title=
  {
    title="e_dyn_188785"
    nick=nick_the_just          hist=yes
    base_title="k_mongolia"
    is_custom=yes
    is_dynamic=yes
    claim=
    {
      title=k_bulgaria
      pressed=yes
      weak=yes
    }
    claim=
    {
      title=c_karvuna
      pressed=yes
    }
    claim=
    {
      title=c_tyrnovo
    }
    claim=
    {
      title=c_mesembria
      pressed=yes
    }
  }
```

And here's the relevant parts of my grammar:

```
property: key ASSIGNMENT value { insertProp(stack[scopeLevel], $key.text, currentVal) };

key: (LOWERCASE | UPPERCASE | UNDERSCORE | DIGIT | DOT | bool)+;
value: 
  bool { currentVal = $bool.text === 'yes' } 
  | string { currentVal = $string.text.replace(/\"/gi, '') } 
  | number { currentVal = parseFloat($number.text, 10) } 
  | date { currentVal = $date.text }
  | specific_value { currentVal = $specific_value.text }
  | (numberArray { currentVal = toArray($numberArray.text) }| array)
  | object
  ;

bool: 'yes' | 'no';
number: DASH? (DIGIT+ | (DIGIT+ '.' DIGIT+));
string:
  '"' 
  ( number
    | bool
    | specific_value 
    | NONALPLHA 
    | UNDERSCORE 
    | DOT 
    | OPEN_CURLY_BRACES 
    | CLOSE_CURLY_BRACES 
  )* 
  '"'
  ;

specific_value: (LOWERCASE | UPPERCASE | UNDERSCORE | DASH | bool)+ ;


WS: ([\t\r\n] | ' ') -> channel(HIDDEN);
NEWLINE: ( '\r'? '\n' | '\r')+ -> channel(HIDDEN);
```

So, as you can see, the input syntax can have property values that are strings but are not delimited by `"`. And, in fact, for some odd reason, sometimes the next property appears on the same line. Ignoring the WS and NEWLINE means that the parser doesn't recognise that `specific_value` rule terminates so it grabs part of the next key as well. See output example below:

```
{
  game_speed: 4,
  mapmode: 0,
  dyn_title:
  { 
     title: 'e_dyn_188785',
     nick: 'nick_the_just\t\t\this',
     t: true,
     base_title: 'k_mongolia',
     is_custom: true,
     is_dynamic: true,
     claim: { title: 'k_bulgaria\n\t\t\t\tpresse', d: true, weak: true },
     claim2: { title: 'c_karvuna\n\t\t\t\tpresse', d: true },
     claim3: { title: 'c_tyrnovo' },
     claim4: { title: 'c_mesembria\n\t\t\t\tpresse', d: true 
  } 
},
```

What's an appropriate solution here to specify that `specific_value` shouldn't grab any characters once it reaches a WS or NEWLINE?

Thanks in advance! :D

Comment: Why do you not handle strings and numbers at the lexer stage?

Comment: oversight? inexperience? just didn't think to do it that way? 
I'm not really seeing how that would help though?

Comment: By glueing together `specific_value `-characters (and `string`-chars, and `number`-characters) in the parser, you have trouble of determining if `a b` is a single `specific_value` (`ab`) or 2 `specific_value`s (`a` and `b`) because the space in between is put on a different channel by the lexer. Handling such cases in the lexer would eliminate this. I'll write a quick demo.

Comment: aha! yes, that makes sense, I'll try it out! thanks!
I'd still very much appreciate the short demo if you could :)

Comment: No problem. Added a quick demo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd handle as much a possible in the lexer (like identifiers, numbers and strings). That could look like this in your case:

```
grammar JsonLike;

parse
 : object? EOF
 ;

object
 : '{' key_value* '}'
 ;

key_value
 : key '=' value
 ;

key
 : SPECIFIC_VALUE
 | BOOL
 // More tokens that can be a key?
 ;

value
 : object
 | array
 | BOOL
 | STRING
 | NUMBER
 | SPECIFIC_VALUE
 ;

array
 : '[' value+ ']'
 ;

BOOL
 : 'yes'
 | 'no'
 ;

STRING
 : '"' ( ~["\\] | '\\' ["\\] )* '"'
 ;

NUMBER
 : '-'? [0-9]+ ( '.' [0-9]+ )?
 ;

SPECIFIC_VALUE
 : [a-zA-Z_] [a-zA-Z_0-9]*
 ;

SPACES
 : [ \t\r\n]+ -> channel(HIDDEN)
 ;
```

Resulting in the following parse:

[image]